# How to write ruby code in order to display "day" by using day = Date.today.wday method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing my Ruby assignment from school.
I need to make day (Sunday, Monday, etc) appears on the calendars application.
Below are the original code in the question I received;

```rb
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    getWeek
    @plan = Plan.new
  end

  def create
    Plan.create(plan_params)
    redirect_to action: :index
  end

  private

  def plan_params
    params.require(:calendars).permit(:date, :plan)
  end

  def getWeek
    wdays = ['(Sun)','(Mon)','(Tue)','(Wed)','(Thu)','(Fri)','(Sat)']

    @todays_date = Date.today
   
    @week_days = []

    plans = Plan.where(date: @todays_date..@todays_date + 6)

    7.times do |x|
      today_plans = []
      plans.each do |plan|
        today_plans.push(plan.plan) if plan.date == @todays_date + x
      end
      days = { :month => (@todays_date + x).month, :date => (@todays_date+x).day, :plans => today_plans}
      @week_days.push(days)
    end

  end
end
```

I tried writing the code as below:

```rb
@todays_date = Date.today.wday
```

I expected to see the day (Sun, Mon, etc) appear on the application

Comment: Doesn’t wday return an integer? Isn’t that integer an index into your wdays array?

Comment: Is `getWeek` your implementation? What are the expected values for the instance variables it sets? In addition: is `@todays_date` being printed in the calendar view?

Comment: You need to share the HTML portion of it so we can understand what is being rendered

Answer (score 3):

Today is a Wednesday. When you want to translate a date to the string representation of the weekday, then you can use [`Date#strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/exts/date/Date.html#method-i-strftime) like this:

```
Date.today.strftime("%A")
#=> "Wednesday"
Date.today.strftime("%a")
#=> "Wed"

Date.today.strftime("(%a)")
#=> "(Wed)"
```